# Документация для less под node.js

Tags: node.js, less

Здравствуйте. Где можно взять документацию для использования less в node.js? На официальном сайте [нашел](http://lesscss.org/#using-less-usage-in-code) только два примера по этому поводу.

Comment: А вам что нужно?

Comment: @lampa, по ссылке, что я привел, есть два примера. Там демонстрируется использование метода render (ну с ним более или менее ясно) и класс Parser, с методом parse, который в callback-функции возвращает загадочный объект tree. Хотелось бы узнать про другие методы Parser-а, что это за tree, какие еще методы/свойства есть у объектов less, Parser и других.